# How we can fill background image in rect based on rectangle id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, d3.js, svg

I am new to d3 js and I want to fill background image to rectangle based on the id of rect.

Here is my sample code:-

```
<rect x="168.42105263157893" y="43.609022556390975" width="160" height="40" stroke="#f00" fill="url(#venus)" id="aeb3d127-946e-4e56-be45-38db260a81f7" data-pdf-annotate-type="stamp_button" aria-hidden="true" transform="scale(1.33) rotate(0) translate(0, 0)" pageNumber="1" class="pico" style="fill: rgb(243, 243, 243);"></rect>

var imgUrl = "http://localhost:4200/assets/icon-feature-1.png";

d3.selectAll("svg").append("defs") 
               .append("pattern")
               .attr("id", "venus")
               .attr('patternUnits', 'userSpaceOnUse')
               .attr("width", x)
               .attr("height", y)
               .append("image")
               .attr("xlink:href", imgUrl);

d3.selectAll("svg").select('rect[id="aeb3d127-946e-4e56-be45-38db260a81f7"]')
                   .attr('class', 'pico')
                   .attr('height', height)
                   .attr('width', width)
                   .attr('x', x)
                   .attr('y', y)
                   .attr("fill", "url(#venus)");
```

Comment: So the rectangle with id "venus" has the color that you want in this rectangle, right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [D3 - Add background fill to rect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26535078/d3-add-background-fill-to-rect)

Comment: @Nisarg I just want to fill background image based on the id of rectangle.